# Callback not getting executed when I expect it

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I have the following code that uses fetch. From what I understand, the callback function will not be invoked until the promise is fulfilled. Because of that, I was expecting the callback functions to be executed in the middle of processing other things (such as the for loop). However, it is not doing what I expect. My code is as follows:

```
console.log("Before fetch")
fetch('https://example.com/data')
  .then(function(response){
    console.log("In first then")
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(json){
    console.log("In second then")
    console.log(json)
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log("An error has occured")
    console.log(error)

  })
console.log("After fetch")
for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
   if (i % 10000 == 0)
      console.log(i)
}

console.log("The End")
```

Rather than the callback being immediately run when the promise is fulfilled, it seems to wait until all the rest of my code is processed before the callback function is activated. Why is this?

The output of my code looks like this:

```
Before fetch
After fetch
0
10000
.
.
.
970000
980000
990000
The End
In first then
In second then
```

However, I was expecting the last two lines to appear somewhere prior to this point. What is going on here and how can I change my code so that it reflects when the promise is actually fulfilled?

Comment: 1M operations are nothing for nowadays CPUs, are you sure that your request takes very little time ( talking in milliseconds here).

Comment: which callback are you referring to? maybe i'm missing something but, in your code the for loop is separate from your promise chain... as @NiVeR mentioned it appears to be working correctly.

Comment: everything after fetch.whatever. will run immediately after the fetch starts. the then and catch blocks are running in parallel with your for loop

Comment: You can use `async/await` for forcing order of tasks

Comment: I would also suggest watching this great explanation of event loop https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that the for loop you're running afterwards is a *long, synchronous block of code*. That is the reason why synchronous APIs are deprecated / not recommended in JavaScript, as they block all asynchronous callbacks from executing until completion. JavaScript is not multithreaded, and it does not have concepts like interrupts in C, so if the thread is executing a large loop, nothing else will have the chance to run until that loop is finished.

In Node.js, the `child_process` API allows you to run daemon processes, and the Web Worker API for browsers allows concurrent processes to run in parallel, both of these using serialized event-based messaging to communicate between threads, but aside from that, everything in the above paragraph applies universally to JavaScript.

In general, a possible solution to breaking up long synchronous processes like the one you have there is *batching*. Using promises, you could rewrite the for loop like this:

```js
(async () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
     if (i % 10000 == 0) {
        console.log(i);
        // release control for minimum of 4 ms
        await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 0); });
     }
  }
})().then(() => {
  console.log("The End");
});

setTimeout(() => { console.log('Can interrupt loop'); }, 1);
```

<sup>Reason for 4ms minimum: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified</sup>

Comment: would it be possible to 'lower' the priority of iterations in the call stack by using `setTimeout(function() { }, 0);` to place execution at the end? Giving priority to fulfilment of the promise when resolved?

Comment: @lkroneman Only if the promises have already resolved by the time setTimeout delay is complete. the callback queue is emptied first in first out, so if they aren't resolved yet, their callbacks will be inserted after the setTimeout callback, thus causing them to be delayed until the for loop has completed.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how fast is your promise fulfilled. Callbacks added to **Event Loop** and will invoke after all synchronous tasks are finished. In this example synchronous task is for loop. You can try event with `setTimeout` with  `0ms`, it will also work after loop. Remember JS is single-threaded and doesn't support parallel tasks.

Referance:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score -1):

There's no guarantee when the callback will execute. The for-loop requires very little processing time, so it's possible that the JS engine just decided to wait until it's over to complete the callback functions. There's no certain way of forcing a specific order of functions either unless you chain them as callbacks.

Comment: it is impossible for a callback to be called while other javascript (in this case a for loop) is currently being executed.